# cakephp: retrieving data from table

Tags: cakephp, model

I am trying to retrieve data from a table but I want the return value to be a single list of values (not a key-value array) like:

```
$data = $this->find( 'list', array ('fields' => 'name');
```

**current output:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => WINNIPEG ) ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => ALBERTA) ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => MONTREAL ) ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => POPLAR PT ) )
```

**What I want:**

```
Array(
WINNIPEG,
ALBERTA,
MONTREAL,
POPLAR PT
)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot thanks for editing my question! I am new here

Comment: You're welcome. Questions with poor formatting and irrelevant/incorrect tags tend to be poorly received here, so make sure everything looks good in the preview before posting.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep that in mind next time :)

Comment: Another little pointer: I see you changed from the `cakephp` tag to `cakephp-2.0`. Hovering over the tag shows the tag description, which says "Questions about the 2.0.x branch of the CakePHP MVC framework. If your question applies to CakePHP in general, use the tag [cakephp]." Unless your question applies *specifically* to CakePHP 2.0.x (like a bug in a particular version), I would follow the advice in the tag description and use the `cakephp` tag, since a lot more people follow it.

Comment: Thanks again! I changed it back to cakephp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model that you are calling the `->find()` on, set your displayField attribute to `name`.

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'name';
}
```

This will make the `$this->find('list')` output the name field by default.

Read more about displayField [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#displayfield).

Note: If you specify fields when calling `->find()` you should prefix the field name with the model name ie. `$this->find('list', ['fields' => 'MyModel.name']`

Answer (score 0):

You can't get

```
Array(
    WINNIPEG,
    ALBERTA,
    MONTREAL,
    POPLAR PT
)
```

What you will get will be

```
Array(
   0 => WINNIPEG,
   1 => ALBERTA,
   2 => MONTREAL,
   3 => POPLAR PT
)
```

You need to first do what @Hippie said (Set display field on your model) by

```
public $displayField = 'name';
```

and then to get the name list

```
$namesList = $this->ModelName->find('list');
```

$namesList print=>

```
Array(
   0 => WINNIPEG,
   1 => ALBERTA,
   2 => MONTREAL,
   3 => POPLAR PT
)
```

If you want to get a string like this:

```
"WINNIPEG, ALBERTA, MONTREAL, POPLAR PT"
```

You can use php function implode(',', $namesList);

Comment: thanks! I will remember implode function next time I need a string :)

Answer (score -1):

`$this->find('list',...)` is for returning key value pairs, where the key is the `id` of the record, and the `value` usually a significant value, like `name` or `title`.

You need to call `$this->find('all',...)`, with the proper conditions, field specifications, etc. That will give you an array of arrays, one for each record returned, and each of those will have a key for the Model name, `City` for example, and as value another array with each field selected as key, and each field's value as value.

So, to get the first name, you would need to do `$results[0]['City']['name'];`

You can transform this datastructure to the one you want with a foreach statement or similar.

A classic Cake way is to use the `Hash` Utility Class. To get the array you want in this example you would do: `Hash::extract($results, '{n}.City.name');`

Check the docs for the Hash Utility class, it has lots of handy stuff.

Cheers!

Comment: Using Hash::extract() for this simple query is not a good practice. and find all make the job harder and he won't get what he expect.

Comment: he wants "a single list of values", and not key-value, like primaryKey->value. Why hash::extract is not good practice? and why find->all makes the work harder? please explain :)

Comment: thanks! I tried using $this->find('all',...) before but I think it returns a nested array that's why I didn't use it. The Hash::extract is a good idea! I will use it next time :)